# Serving translation files in S3 using i18next, yet getting i18next::translator: missingKey and page showing keys only even when files loaded properly

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next, i18next-http-backend

*Edit*

After debugging, it seems that in the original code using file system, `react-i18next`'s `useSSR` gets the listed `namespacesRequired` and have it loaded already, however when changing it to using s3 path with `i18next-http-backend`, the same step returns the listed `namespacesRequired` but with empty objects.
e.g.

```
{
  en: {
    common: {},
    error: {},
  }
}
```

May I know if I have missed any step?

*End of Edit*

I am trying to use S3 bucket (accessed through CDN) to serve our translation files.
It seems like the library is able to download the files correctly (loaded correctly based on Network tab and console log), however it is still saying that the key for the translation is missing. The page is only showing the keys as well at the moment.

**Package version:**

```
"next-i18next": "7.0.1",
```

**i18n.js configuration**

```
const nextI18NextInstance = new NextI18Next({
  use: [I18NextHttpBackend],
  defaultNS: 'common',
  defaultLanguage,
  fallbackLng: defaultLanguage,
  // localePath: path.resolve('static/locales'),
  localePath: CDN_DOMAIN,
  otherLanguages: languageKeys.filter((x) => x !== defaultLanguage),
  detection: {
    lookupQuerystring: lookupKey,
    lookupCookie: CookieTypes.LOCALE.name,
    order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'header'],
    cookieDomain: COOKIE_DOMAIN,
    cookieMinutes: 20160,
  },
  backend: {
    loadPath: (lng, ns) => {
      const url = `${CDN_DOMAIN}/${lng}/${ns}.json`;
      console.log('Translation URL ', url, ns);
      return url;
    },
    crossDomain: true
  },
  debug: true
})
const i18nRef = nextI18NextInstance.i18n
```

**Console log:**

```
i18next: initialized **see initializedObject below**
I18n.js:74 Translation URL  https://**cdn path**/en/common.json ['common']
i18next.js:22 i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace common for language en {page: {title: "some value", description: "some value"}, nav: {…}, …}
i18next.js:22 i18next: languageChanged en
i18next.js:22 i18next::translator: missingKey en common page.title page.title
i18next.js:22 i18next::translator: missingKey en common page.description page.description
```

initializedObject

```
{
    "debug": true,
    "initImmediate": true,
    "ns": ["common", "notifications", "error"],
    "defaultNS": "common",
    "fallbackLng": ["en"],
    "fallbackNS": false,
    "whitelist": ["de","ko","en","cimode"],
    "nonExplicitWhitelist": false,
    "supportedLngs": ["de","ko","en","cimode"],
    "nonExplicitSupportedLngs": false,
    "load": "currentOnly",
    "preload": false,
    "simplifyPluralSuffix": true,
    "keySeparator": ".",
    "nsSeparator": ":",
    "pluralSeparator": "_",
    "contextSeparator": "_",
    "partialBundledLanguages": false,
    "missingKeyHandler": false,
    "missingInterpolationHandler": false,
    "postProcess": false,
    "postProcessPassResolved": false,
    "interpolation": {"escapeValue": false, "formatSeparator": ","},
    "defaultLanguage": "en",
    "otherLanguages": ["de","ko"],
    "localePath": "https://xxx", // cdn path value
    "localeStructure": "{{lng}}/{{ns}}",
    "localeExtension": "json",
    "localeSubpaths": {},
    "use": [null],
    "browserLanguageDetection": true,
    "serverLanguageDetection": true,
    "customDetectors": [],
    "detection": {
        "caches": ["cookie"],
        "cookieSameSite": "strict",
        "lookupCookie": "locale",
        "order": ["querystring","cookie","header"],
        "lookupQuerystring": "locale",
        "cookieDomain": "yyy", // cookie domain
        "cookieMinutes": 20160,
        "lookupLocalStorage": "i18nextLng",
        "excludeCacheFor": ["cimode"]
    },
    "react": {"wait": true, "useSuspense": false},
    "strictMode": true,
    "errorStackTraceLimit": 0,
    "shallowRender": false,
    "backend": {
        "crossDomain": true,
        "addPath": "/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}",
        "allowMultiLoading": false,
        "reloadInterval": false,
        "customHeaders": {},
        "queryStringParams": {},
        "withCredentials": false,
        "overrideMimeType": false,
        "requestOptions": {
            "mode": "cors",
            "credentials": "same-origin",
            "cache": "default"
        }
    },
    "allLanguages": ["de","ko","en"],
   ...
}
```